# Magento2: issues after composer update with store ID

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

I updated all modules:

```
composer update
```

But after update I try add product to the basket and after "Go to checkout" return issue:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found
#0 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(167): Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->getById('4')
#1 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(119): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore('4')
#2 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Store.php(29): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore('4')
#3 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49): Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope('4')
#4 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores', '4')
#5 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/mirasvit/module-rewards/src/Rewards/Model/Checkout/ConfigProviderPlugin.php(146): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('carriers/freesh...', 'stores', '4')
#6 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/mirasvit/module-rewards/src/Rewards/Model/Checkout/ConfigProviderPlugin.php(110): Mirasvit\Rewards\Model\Checkout\ConfigProviderPlugin->isShippingMinOrderSet(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor))
#7 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Mirasvit\Rewards\Model\Checkout\ConfigProviderPlugin->afterGetConfig(Object(Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor), Array)
#8 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#9 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getConfig', Array, Array)
#10 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/CompositeConfigProvider.php(38): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->getConfig()
#11 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Shipping.php(64): Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider->getConfig()
#12 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/shipping.phtml(28): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping->getCheckoutConfig()
#13 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/user/d...')
#14 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping), '/home/user/d...', Array)
#15 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/user/d...')
#16 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#17 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#18 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('checkout.cart.s...')
#19 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart.s...')
#20 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart.s...')
#21 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('checkout.cart.s...', false)
#22 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('checkout.cart.s...', false)
#23 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('cart.bottom.bor...', false)
#24 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('cart.bottom.bor...')
#25 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('cart.bottom.bor...')
#26 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('cart.bottom.bor...', false)
#27 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('cart.bottom.bor...', false)
#28 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('cart.bottom.col...', false)
#29 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('cart.bottom.col...')
#30 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('cart.bottom.col...')
#31 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('cart.bottom.col...', false)
#32 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('cart.bottom.col...', false)
#33 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('cart.bottom', false)
#34 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('cart.bottom')
#35 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('cart.bottom')
#36 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('cart.bottom', false)
#37 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('cart.bottom', false)
#38 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('checkout.cart.c...', false)
#39 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart.c...')
#40 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart.c...')
#41 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('checkout.cart.c...', false)
#42 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('checkout.cart.c...', false)
#43 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('checkout.cart.i...', false)
#44 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart.i...')
#45 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart.i...')
#46 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('checkout.cart.i...', true)
#47 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(507): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('checkout.cart.i...', true)
#48 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Interceptor.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('with-items', true)
#49 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart.phtml(15): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Interceptor->getChildHtml('with-items')
#50 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/user/d...')
#51 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Interceptor), '/home/user/d...', Array)
#52 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Interceptor.php(323): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/user/d...')
#53 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Interceptor->fetchView('/home/user/d...')
#54 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#55 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Interceptor.php(648): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#56 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Interceptor->toHtml()
#57 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('checkout.cart')
#58 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart')
#59 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart')
#60 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('checkout.cart', false)
#61 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('checkout.cart', false)
#62 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false)
#63 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#64 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#65 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false)
#66 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content', false)
#67 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main', false)
#68 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#69 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#70 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', false)
#71 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main', false)
#72 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns', false)
#73 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#74 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#75 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', false)
#76 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns', false)
#77 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content', false)
#78 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#79 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#80 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', false)
#81 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content', false)
#82 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
#83 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#84 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#85 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#86 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(586): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#87 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
#88 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#89 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#90 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#91 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(955): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#92 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#93 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', Array)
#94 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#95 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#96 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#97 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#98 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#99 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#100 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#101 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/MGS/Mpanel/Block/Framework/Page/Interceptor.php(156): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#102 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#103 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#104 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#105 /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#106 {main}
```

update2:

```
MySQL returned an empty result (zero rows). (The query took 0.0001 seconds (s).)
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0
[Edit in line] [Edit] [Create PHP code]
 Modified records: 0. (The query took 0.0003 seconds (s).)
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code = 'admin'
[Edit in line] [Edit] [Create PHP code]
 Modified records: 0. (It took 0.0002 seconds (s) to complete the query.)
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name = 'Default'
[Edit in line] [Edit] [Create PHP code]
 Modified records: 0. (It took 0.0008 seconds (s) to complete the query.)
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code = 'admin'
[Edit in line] [Edit] [Create PHP code]
 Modified records: 0. (It took 0.0001 seconds (s) to complete the query.)
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code = 'NOT LOGGED IN'
[Edit in line] [Edit] [Create PHP code]
 MySQL returned an empty result (zero rows). (The query took 0.0001 seconds (s).)
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Run This Query On Database And Try :-**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: I run this query, but no result. Please check my update

Comment: Clear chache and check

Comment: I try deleted folder generated and also clear cache but still the same issue

Comment: check log file..

Comment: In log file there is no any information. Can you please try add product to the basket and then go to checkout? Then you reproduce this issue. Gerris.pl